# Amazon Athena not able to read data from partition

Tags: amazon-athena

I am working on partition in athena. I have a directory in s3 where date wise files are placed. I am trying to create a date partitioned table and set the location of each partition to the file of that date. Although the set location query for partition is running successfully, I am not able to see data in that partition through select query.

After executing below query i can see the data : 
alter table tbl_name partition (date='2018-05-28') set location 's3://bucket_name//test/'
 But not after executing this :
alter table tbl_name partition (date='2018-05-28') set location 's3://bucket_name//test/test.csv'

Thus if i set location to a directory it is able to pick data but not when setting location to a file.
But I need to set the location of a partition to a file name. This is working prefectly in Hive. Need Help for athena.

Answer (score 2):

If your have the folder structure like this,

```
S3://bucket/myfodler/logs/2018/04/02/file1.csv
S3://bucket/myfodler/logs/2018/04/02/file2.csv
S3://bucket/myfodler/logs/2018/04/03/file1.csv
S3://bucket/myfodler/logs/2018/04/03/file2.csv
```

Then you can create partition like,

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD
  PARTITION (YEAR = '2018', MONTH='04', day='02') LOCATION 'S3://bucket/myfodler/logs/2018/04/02'
```

In your case,

`s3://bucket_name//test/test.csv`  -is not a proper structure to create the partition.

If you share your s3 folder structure, then I can try to help you on this.

For more about Athena partition: [Read Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html)